# How to get Angle of velocity to rotate a bullet?

Tags: iphone, math, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, velocity

I have this:

```
CGPoint vel = hudLayer.rightJoystick.velocity;

            CCBullet* sp = [CCBullet spriteWithFile:@"green.png"];
            sp.position = player.position;
            [self addChild:sp z:-10];

            vel = ccpMult(ccpNormalize(vel), 300);
sp.rotation = //how to get the rotation out of the velocity?
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
float angle = atan2f(vel.y, vel.x);
```

Comment: thanks worked but i needed do to this:             sp.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(-1*angle);

Comment: Yeah I should probably have explained this will give you a result in radians (0.. pi*2) not degrees (0.. 360)